# Find and replace first space in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I have a string:

`s = "one two three"`
How do I replace first space with `&nbsp;`?

The string returned should be `"one&nbsp;two three"`.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: "not constructive" and "not a real question" are not grounds for closing this question, and I suspect "too localized" isn't either. The OP should have tried googling for the RDoc for string, but that's not grounds for closing. "General reference" isn't grounds for closing on Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason

Comment: I agree, I edited the question to make it a real question. Why clutter up search results with closed questions when we can be proactive and clean it up?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good point. I've now voted to re-open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the sub method on String only replaces the first occurrence. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub

so this will do the job

```
s.sub(" ", "&nbsp;")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to check ruby methods, tried to find the solution through a regexp

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
s.sub(/ /,'&nbsp;')
```

Comment: he only want to replace the first occurrence, my answer also includes gsub I know, but I also answer the true question.

Answer (score 2):

```
s.sub(" ", "&nbsp")
```

This will replace only the first occurrence.

```
s.gsub(" ", "&nbsp")
```

This will replace all occurrences.

Why do you only want to replace the first one?